# Stability of solutions of linear homogenous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $y_1,...,y_n$ form a basis to the solution space of $y^{(n)}+a_{n-1}y^{(n-1)}+...+a_1y'+a_0y=0$. If $y_1,...,y_n$ are bounded for $x>x_0$, does that mean that the trivial solution is stable (but not asymptotically so), and hence all solutions are stable? Why? (my difficulty is understanding why boundedness means stability).

Comment: What is the definition you're given to stability? Without it it is difficult to answer your question. The definition I know, is that stability of a solution means that solutions with initial conditions to it doesn't diverge from it (and in your case, since all solutions are bounded, then all are stable), and asymptotic stability is saying that their difference approaches to zero.

Comment: The definition is as you said: a solutions is stable if for all epsilon there is a delta and some x, such that if the difference at x between the given solution and any other solution does not exceed delta, then it will not exceed epsilon from there on. Why does the imply that if all solutions are bounded then they are stable?